# UIWebView disable zooming when scalesPageToFit is ON

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

Is there any way to disable zooming when Scales page to Fit is ON ??

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This works for me:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
scrollView.delegate = self;//self must be UIScrollViewDelegate

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  return nil;
}
```

UPDATE: For iOS 5 or higher get scrollView like this:

```
webview.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Excellent solution, works perfectly and using an if statement in the method, you can choose to return `nil` or forward the message on to `super` in which case zoom is re-enabled (depending on what content you're displaying).

Comment: Starting from iOS 5 you can use `webView.scrollView.delegate = self;`.

Comment: This is also seems like a solid way of disabling zooming for WKWebView, which has no scalesPageToFit flag

Comment: From where I will get the delegate if I am using UIWebView inside UIViewController.
---------------scrollView.delegate = self;//self must be UIScrollViewDelegate------------
I mean from where I should assign -----self----?

Comment: self is your UIViewController, or any other object, base idea is scrollView should ask some delegate for viewForZoomingInScrollView, so this delegate should implement this method

Answer (score 12):

Instead of using

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
scrollView.delegate = self; //self must be UIScrollViewDelegate

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return nil;
}
```

You can use this:

```
webview.scrollView.delegate = self;

-(UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView {
    return nil;
}
```

Second option is better and full-proof. First logic could fail in future SDKs.

Answer (score 4):

There's property called `scrollView` in `UIWebView`. Through it you can define this.
To be more specific it should look like this:

```
myWebView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
myWebView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
```

Comment: Wrong the zoom is still there even if you set the zoom levels to 1.0

Comment: This actually works if put in `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView ` of the webview's delegate function

Comment: Sorry, this just doesn't work for me, even if placed in webViewDidFinishLoad.

Comment: +1 Worked for me if I used 'webView.scrollView.zoomScale' instead of 1.0, and do it inside the 'webViewDidFinishLoad' (remember to set the web view delegate)

Comment: This worked.. Setting the minimum and maximum zoom scale lets the scrollView of the WebView know how much it can zoom in or out..+1 for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **scalesPageToFit**
>
> A Boolean value determining whether the webpage scales to fit the view
> and the user can change the scale.
>
> @property(nonatomic)  BOOL scalesPageToFit

*Discussion*

> If YES, the webpage is scaled to fit and the user can zoom in and zoom
> out. If NO, user zooming is disabled. The default value is NO.

So if you want to change that behavior, you will probably have to subclass UIWebView.

Answer (score 3):

Edit:
Implement delegate method

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

For your web view and in it add folowing code:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"$('body').bind('touchmove', function(event) { event.preventDefault() });"];
```

The problem is this also disable the scroll, because it disable the move of touch.
If you want to keep the scroll you have to write a java script that will overwrite the viewport meta tag with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: It seems that you are write, I am searching for a solution and i will edit

Answer (score -1):

so it works at me:

```
NSString *fullURL = @"http://google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
_webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
_webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
_webView.scalesPageToFit = FALSE;
[_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```