# iOS UIWebView: Disable this (zoom out) state but have zoom in enabled

Tags: ios, uiwebview, mobile-safari, viewport, pinchzoom

I have set the following viewport tag in html file using UIWebView.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">`

Now, when user piches out, I get this effect as shown in the image. 
I want to disable this effect but still have the ability to zoom in.

Tried by setting UIWebView's bounce to NO, but still this problem persists.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it by using bouncesZoom property of UIScrollView(property of UIWebView) as below-

[webView.scrollView setBouncesZoom:NO];

Comment: You are welcome. It is helpful to go through apple documentation before using any control.

Comment: @RahulWakade Can you help me to stop Zoom out webview as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653491/disable-zoom-in-a-uiwebview-but-keep-other-user-interaction

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062195/uiwebview-disable-zooming-when-scalespagetofit-is-on

Check it out