# Disable zoom in a UIWebView but keep other user interaction

Tags: ios, ios7, uiwebview, user-interaction

I have a UIWebView that shows some text, I want to disable zoom/unzoom but I want to detect when users tap on a link. I have tried with disabling MultiTouch but zoom is still working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the minimumZoomScale and maximumZoomScale on your webview's UIScrollView to be 1.0 should prevent the webview from zooming.

```
webview.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
webview.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
  return nil;
}
```