# Stop WebView from Auto Zooming In

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a webView and when the content initially loads it looks perfect and fits nicely but as soon as it completes loading it automatically zooms way in.  Is there a way to stop this?  Ive tried more combinations than I can possibly post here.

Many Thanks.

The Code I'm using is pretty straight forward:

```
NSString *urlString = @"some_url";
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[cell.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIWebView disable zooming when scalesPageToFit is ON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062195/uiwebview-disable-zooming-when-scalespagetofit-is-on)

Comment: Tried that page already, didn't work.

Comment: can you add some more code related to scroll, I react the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you do:

In your UI controller that owns the web view, make it a `UIWebViewDelegate`. Then where you set the URL to load, set the delegate as the controller:

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/50941418/2-build.html";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];  
webView.delegate = self;
```

And finally implement the `webViewDidFinishLoad`: to correctly set the zoom level:

**This option will applicable from iOS 5.0 and >**

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView{
CGSize contentSize = theWebView.scrollView.contentSize;
CGSize viewSize = theWebView.bounds.size;
float rw = viewSize.width / contentSize.width;
 theWebView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = rw;
theWebView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = rw;
  theWebView.scrollView.zoomScale = rw;  
}
```

I hope this helps...

Option B, you can try to alter the HTML (this example does the job but is less than perfect from an HTML parsing standpoint. I just wanted to illustrate my point. It does work for your example, and probably most cases. The inset of 40 can probably be detected programmatically, I didn't try to research that.

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/50941418/2-build.html";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding] error:nil];
NSRange range = [html rangeOfString:@"<body"];
if(range.location != NSNotFound) {
// Adjust style for mobile
float inset = 40;
 NSString *style = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<style>div {max-width: %fpx;}</style>", self.view.bounds.size.width - inset];
html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", [html substringToIndex:range.location], style, [html substringFromIndex:range.location]];
}
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:url];
```

Comment: Didn't work.  Does it make a difference that the webView is calling a webcam stream?