# iOS Disable Initial Zoom in webview?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I need to Disable zooming for UIWebview iOS for swift 2.2. 
I am trying like this:

```
self.webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
self.webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
```

But this is not helping. Is there any other way I can disable zoom while the page loads for the first time?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
let scrollView = webView.subviews.objectAtIndex(0)
scrollView.delegate = self

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return someView
}
```

**UPDATE**: For iOS 5 or higher get scrollView like this:

```
webview.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

You can try this also:

use 'webView.scrollView.zoomScale' instead of 1.0, and do it inside the 'webViewDidFinishLoad' (remember to set the web view delegate)

Comment: Need a swift version

Comment: this is swift version

Comment: @sivajee Battina, in case of returning `someView`, i found that returning `nil` is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off `scalesPageToFit` for the webView and set the zoom level manually for the first time loading. [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062195/uiwebview-disable-zooming-when-scalespagetofit-is-on)

Hope this helps.